# Change site background colour with colour picker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [this colour picker](http://jscolor.com/try.php) for my site. What I need to do is to change background of my website **body/html** when selection is in progress. Just like it changes the background of textbox there.

I've looked at the JS file itself but found it a bit complex. I added `document.body.style.background = styleElement.jscStyle.backgroundColor;` between lines 410 - 430 but nothing changed.

How can I achieve it.

Thanks

Comment: I would use `document.body.style.backgroundColor` just to be sure.

Comment: Didn't work. I think I'm adding that code in wrong place but no luck so far.

Comment: I wouldn't change the source code of the library you use too. Use an event handler instead. `document.getElementById('colorpicker').addEventListener('change', changeColor);` or `document.getElementById('colorpicker').onChange = changeColor;`

Comment: Why aren't you using actual jQuery? :P http://api.jquery.com/change/ on the color picker field and then trigger the body background style to change based on the value that is in the color picker field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [section 8](http://jscolor.com/try.php#onchange) of the Demos page you have "Onchange event":

You need to create the `input` like this:

```
<input class="color"
    onchange="document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#'+this.color">
```

My guess is that in your example you have forgot to add `#` before the color HEX code.

Comment: The problem was I was styling html tag in my css. Removed it and works fine now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add a class (`.colorPicker`) to the color picker input field and then do this in jQuery:

```
'use strict';
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".colorPicker").change(function(){
        $('body').css('background-color', $(this).css('background-color'));
    });
});
```